# Open-RAN/O-RAN timing requirements

Tags: architecture

I am trying to deeply understand Open-RAN/O-RAN timing requirements and what factors affect them.

I have googled and found that the distance between RU and DU affects wheater the requirements on the link are stringent or not.

Another question: what is the difference between timing requirements and synchronization in this context?